# Parse mutually exclusive input arguments with MATLAB's input parser

Tags: matlab, optional-arguments

I have a function that has at least two required input arguments. Depending on the value of the second argument, there might be a third required input argument. I am wondering what is the best way to code a robust function that incorporates these requirements using MATLAB's input parser?

The function may look like this:

```
function vout = test(ReqInpArg1, ReqInpArg2, varargin)
```

`ReqInpArg2` may hold the following string content:

- `'cash'`
- `'absHurdleRate'`
- `'none'`

If the user chooses `cash`, than another input argument `numCashTicker` needs to be defined as part of `varargin`, e.g. `'numCashTicker', 4`. If `absHurdleRate`has been choosen, a different input parameter has to be defined, e.g. `'hurdleRate', 0.2`. If, on the other hand, `none` has been chosen, none of these input parameter must be defined. As a matter of fact, `numCashTicker` and `hurdleRate` are mutually exclusive, i.e. they must not be defined at the same time. In addition, if the user didn't chose `none`, he must define one of the other varargin input arguments.

What is best practice / the best strategy in order to implement these requirements?

Comment: Can you please post a code sample? Also don't ask for the "best strategy", because it's too general - make it more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution:

```
function vout = test(timeSeries, hurdleRate, varargin) 
    p = inputParser;
    expectedTypes = {'none', 'cash' 'absHurdleRate'}; 
    default_numCashTicker = [];
    default_absHurdleRate = [];
    p.addRequired('timeSeries');
    p.addRequired('hurdleRate',@(x) any(validatestring(x,expectedTypes)));
    p.addParameter('numCashTicker', default_numCashTicker);
    p.addParameter('absHurdleRate', default_absHurdleRate);
    
    parse(p, timeSeries, hurdleRate, varargin{:});

    numCashTicker = p.Results.numCashTicker;

    switch hurdleRate
        case 'none'
            if ~isequal(numCashTicker, default_numCashTicker)
                throw(MException('test:ParsingError', ...
                    '"none" does not require the "numCashTicker" parameter values"'));
            elseif ~isequal(absHurdleRate, default_absHurdleRate)
                throw(MException('test:ParsingError', ...
                    '"none" does not require the "absHurdleRate parameter values"'));
            end

        case 'cash'
            if ~isnumeric(numCashTicker)
                throw(MException('test:ParsingError', ...
                    '"cash" requires a numeric "numCashTicker" parameter value'));
            elseif ~isequal(absHurdleRate, default_absHurdleRate)
                throw(MException('CSmomRoC:ParsingError', ...
                    '"cash" does not require the "absHurdleRate parameter values"'));
            end

        case 'absHurdleRate'
            if ~isnumeric(absHurdleRate)
                throw(MException('CSmomRoC:ParsingError', ...
                    '"absHurdleRate" requires a numeric "absHurdleRate" parameter value'));
            elseif ~isequal(numCashTicker, default_numCashTicker)
                throw(MException('CSmomRoC:ParsingError', ...
                    '"absHurdleRate" does not require the "numCashTicker" parameter value.'));
            end
    end

    ...
    ...
    ...
end;
```